# app deployment is failing after updated to spring boot 2.2.1

Tags: spring-boot

I created a spring boot app with spring boot2.0 and h2 in-memory database,the app is running successfully.After I updated it to spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE ,the deployment is failing.

Here is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SampleServicesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Autowired
    private UserPartnerSource userSource;

    @Autowired
    UserPartnerDao userPartnerDao;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleServicesApplication.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(SampleServicesApplication.class)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {    
        List<UserPartner> userPartner = userSource.getUsers();
        userPartnerDao.saveAll(userPartner);

    }
}

public interface UserPartnerDao extends JpaRepository<UserPartner, Long> {

    @Query("select u from UserPartner u  where u.userAccessToken =?1")
    UserPartner findByToken(String accessToken);

    @Query("select u.userAccessSecret from UserPartner u  where u.userAccessToken =?1")
    String getUserAccessSecret(String accessToken);

}
```

Here is the dependencies I am using in pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency> 

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
          dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
      </depedencies>
```

once I updated from 2.0.8 to 2.2.1 , I am getting the following error when running the application.
I tried different ways, nothing worked for me. any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:337)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:384)
     at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:385)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:62)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.getRepositoryConfigurationExtension(JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.java:54)
     at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.<clinit>(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:76)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:371)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
     ... 6 more
     at com.garmin.gh.apps.wellnessmonitor.GcsWellnessServicesApplication.main(SampleServicesApplication.java:43)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
     ... 34 more
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:463)
     at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
     Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
     ... 27 more
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:170)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
     Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jar file that contains `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` has been corrupted:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
```

Try deleting `spring-orm` from Maven’s local cache and rebuilding. This should cause Maven to download the jar again. Hopefully it won’t corrupt it again.

Comment: I did that ,still having another issue,finally I deleted entire local repository. app is deployed successfully. Thank you so much.